# How to use slow shutter speed on Panasonic DMC-TZ35

Tags: shutter-speed, long-exposure, panasonic

I was wondering how you can set a custom slow shutter speed (long exposure) length above 30 seconds on a Panasonic DMC-TZ35.
Ideally I would want about 2 minutes. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick read of the manual and specs suggests that camera doesn't have a bulb mode (which allows you to open the shutter for long periods), and the slowest shutter speed is 30 seconds in 'starry night' mode.